# How use "Select" Result from Stored procedure in Entity FrameWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure shown below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Save_Customer](@PK int , @Name nvarchar(30) , @Address nvarchar(100) , @CustomerGrp_FK int)
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
    IF (@PK = -1)   
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.[Customer]
        SELECT @Name  , @Address  , @CustomerGrp_FK 

        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY () as IdentityPK
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Customer
        SET Name  = @Name ,Address  = @Address ,CustomerGrp_FK  = @CustomerGrp_FK
        WHERE PK= @PK
    END
```

To use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY () as IdentityPK`, I created below class:

```
public class Save_Customer_MyResult
{
    public int Identity { get; set; }
}
```

then I insert below codes in my EntityContext class:

```
public DbSet<Save_Customer_MyResult> Save_CustomerDB { get; set; }

public virtual  Save_Customer_MyResult Save_Customer1(Nullable<int> pK, string name, string address, Nullable<int> customerGrp_FK)
    {
        return this.Database.SqlQuery<Save_Customer_MyResult>("Save_Customer @PK, @Name, @Address, @CustomerGrp_FK", new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("PK", pK)
            , new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Name", name)
            , new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Address", address)
            , new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("CustomerGrp_FK", customerGrp_FK)).First<Save_Customer_MyResult>();
    }
```

now in my presentation Layer. when I call method. the `Identity` field is 0. :(

```
Customer.Save_Customer_MyResult scr=customercontext.Save_Customer1(-1, txt_Name.Text, txt_Address.Text, Int32.Parse(cmb_GroupName.SelectedValue.ToString()));

       MessageBox.Show(scr.Identity  .ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- according to [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/call-store-procedure-from-entity-framework/). I just made a new `Complex Type`.

2- `stored procedure mapping` for `entity`

[image]

3-then :

```
IEnumerable<Customer.Save_Customer_Result > s= customercontext.Save_Customer(-1, txt_Name.Text, txt_Address.Text,Int32 .Parse( cmb_GroupName.SelectedValue.ToString()));
       MessageBox.Show(s.First<Customer.Save_Customer_Result>().IdentityPK   .ToString());
```